# TikZ pics with transform canvas not working (bug?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I'm making a beamer template for the laboratory I work on. Since I couldn't find an SVG or PDF version of the logo I decided to draw it with tikz (I drew over the original PNG that's why the code is very fixed). I thought that maybe it would be a nice idea to have the template define a `pic` with the logo for future use, so I tried just copy/paste the picture code to a `pic` but the part which makes use of `transform canvas` is not being drawn even though I'm using explicit bounding box...

### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{%
pics/polo/.style={%
    code={%
    \useasboundingbox (-108.12047pt,-54.0623pt) rectangle (108.12047pt,54.0623pt);
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule,xslant=0.6]
    \fill (-1.5mm-81.65935pt,11mm-45.16873pt) coordinate (P) -- ++(20pt,0) -- ++(0,13pt) coordinate (tmp) -- ++(20pt,0) to[out=5,in=0, looseness=2.6] ++(0,20pt) -| cycle
    (tmp) ++(1pt,6pt) -- ++(6pt,0) to[out=5,in=0, looseness=4] ++(1pt,7.75pt) -| cycle;
    \fill[looseness=3.4] (P) ++(29.5mm,0) coordinate (Po) to[out=3, in=0] ++(-2pt,22pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle [looseness=2.5] (Po) ++(-.5pt,5pt) to[out=3, in=0] ++(0pt,12pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle;
    \fill (P) ++(39.25mm,0) coordinate (Pol) -- ++(32pt,0) -- ++(0,6pt) -- ++(-19pt,0) -- ++(0pt,15pt) -| cycle;
    \fill[looseness=3.4] (P) ++(59.5mm,0mm) coordinate (Polo) to[out=3, in=0] ++(-2pt,22pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle [looseness=2.5]  (Polo) ++(-.5pt,5pt) to[out=3, in=0] ++(0pt,12pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \fill (P) ++(-4.5mm,9mm) coordinate (vertex) to[out=50, in=180, looseness=0.75] ++(38mm,10.75mm) coordinate (top) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=180, in=30, looseness=0.95] cycle;
    \fill[#1] (top) ++(4pt,0) coordinate (a) ++(-115:11.5pt) coordinate (b) (a) to[out=0,in=175] ++(27pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=175, in=0] (b) -- cycle;
    \path (vertex) -- coordinate (rot) ++(75.25mm,11.75mm-20mm);
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate around={-180:(rot)}}]
    \fill (P) ++(-4.5mm,9mm) to[out=50, in=180, looseness=0.75] ++(38mm,10.75mm) coordinate (tmp) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=180, in=30, looseness=0.95] cycle;
    \fill[#1] (tmp) ++(4pt,0) coordinate (a) ++(-115:11.5pt) coordinate (b) (a) to[out=0,in=175] ++(27pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=175, in=0] (b) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    }}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic[blue]{polo=orange};

\begin{scope}[yshift=4cm,blue]
    \useasboundingbox (-108.12047pt,-54.0623pt) rectangle (108.12047pt,54.0623pt);
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule,xslant=0.6]
    \fill (-1.5mm-81.65935pt,11mm-45.16873pt) coordinate (P) -- ++(20pt,0) -- ++(0,13pt) coordinate (tmp) -- ++(20pt,0) to[out=5,in=0, looseness=2.6] ++(0,20pt) -| cycle
    (tmp) ++(1pt,6pt) -- ++(6pt,0) to[out=5,in=0, looseness=4] ++(1pt,7.75pt) -| cycle;
    \fill[looseness=3.4] (P) ++(29.5mm,0) coordinate (Po) to[out=3, in=0] ++(-2pt,22pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle [looseness=2.5] (Po) ++(-.5pt,5pt) to[out=3, in=0] ++(0pt,12pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle;
    \fill (P) ++(39.25mm,0) coordinate (Pol) -- ++(32pt,0) -- ++(0,6pt) -- ++(-19pt,0) -- ++(0pt,15pt) -| cycle;
    \fill[looseness=3.4] (P) ++(59.5mm,0mm) coordinate (Polo) to[out=3, in=0] ++(-2pt,22pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle [looseness=2.5]  (Polo) ++(-.5pt,5pt) to[out=3, in=0] ++(0pt,12pt) to[out=185, in=180] cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \fill (P) ++(-4.5mm,9mm) coordinate (vertex) to[out=50, in=180, looseness=0.75] ++(38mm,10.75mm) coordinate (top) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=180, in=30, looseness=0.95] cycle;
    \fill[orange] (top) ++(4pt,0) coordinate (a) ++(-115:11.5pt) coordinate (b) (a) to[out=0,in=175] ++(27pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=175, in=0] (b) -- cycle;
    \path (vertex) -- coordinate (rot) ++(75.25mm,11.75mm-20mm);
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate around={-180:(rot)}}]
    \fill (P) ++(-4.5mm,9mm) to[out=50, in=180, looseness=0.75] ++(38mm,10.75mm) coordinate (tmp) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=180, in=30, looseness=0.95] cycle;
    \fill[orange] (tmp) ++(4pt,0) coordinate (a) ++(-115:11.5pt) coordinate (b) (a) to[out=0,in=175] ++(27pt,-1.5pt) -- ++(-115:11.5pt) to[out=175, in=0] (b) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first logo uses the `pic` `code` directly and the second uses `\pic` command. As it can be seen, the bottom part of the logo is missing, but the bounding box is actually there.

[image]

Comment: Transform canvas doesn't care about any bounding box restrictions. It is directly sent to the driver level with next to none checks You would hardly need transform canvas for such mirror operations. I didn't read carefully but probably `pic` picks up the earlier transformations and rotates it beyond the page border. Check for small values of rotation angles like -2, -5, -10

Comment: From the manual *Just as important, when you use canvas transformations pgf loses track of positions of nodes and of
picture sizes since it does not take the effect of canvas transformations into account when it computes
coordinates of nodes*. So probably rot has moved after transformation.

Comment: Interesting... Ok, so can't do it with `transform canvas` + `rotate around`, too bad. I will use `xscale` and `yscale` and `transform canvas` + `shift`ing. Just need to find the values, again... If you convert your comment to an answer I'll gladly upvote and accept it (and please state that it's not a bug) :)

Comment: Better yet, I can still use `rotate around`, just pass it like `([rotate around={180:(rot)}]P)` and use ``scale=-1`. No need to specify the bounding box then. Perfect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. As.percusse commented transform canvas options are sent directly to driver so bounding box restrictions are overwritten.

The solution used was just restructure the drawing so these restrictions are accommodated (solution is on question comments).